# Telegram Api Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

through the telethon python library I can send messages via inlinebutton if the session is authorized via bot.
If I create a session via phone number I can't send messages with any type of button.
Is it possible to do this or only bots can send buttons?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Only bots are permitted to send messages with buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Inline buttons are a feature exclusive to Telegram bots, and can only be sent by bots. Users who have created sessions via phone numbers are not authorized to use bot functionality.